# HTML formatting not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a relatively simple interactive map, which has flags that act as hyperlinks to the other pages placed on the map image. It works when I open a page in IE, but it's not working in Chrome or Firefox. Here's the code:

```
<title>
Map of Wilmington
</title>

<head>
<style>
l1
{
position:absolute;
top=270px;
left=350px;
}

l2
{
position:absolute;
top=260px;
left=170px;
}

l3
{
position:absolute;
top=320px;
left=540px;
}

l4
{
position:absolute;
top=145px;
left=230px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img SRC="Map 1.jpg" ALT="Map of the city of Wilmington" WIDTH=638 HEIGHT=750></img>

<l1><a HREF="file:///C:/Users/alr2846/Desktop/CSC204/Map2%20UNCW.html">
<img STYLE="border:none;" SRC="Flag.jpg" ALT="University of North Carolina Wilmington
601 South College Road
Wilmington, NC 28407" WIDTH=24 HEIGHT=20></img></a></l1>

<l2><a HREF="file:///C:/Users/alr2846/Desktop/CSC204/Map3%20Downtown.html">
<img STYLE="border:none;" SRC="Flag.jpg" ALT="Downtown Wilmington" WIDTH=24 HEIGHT=20> </img></a></l2>

<l3><a HREF="file:///C:/Users/alr2846/Desktop/CSC204/Map4%20Beach.html">
<img STYLE="border:none;" SRC="Flag.jpg" ALT="Wrightsville Beach" 
WIDTH=24 HEIGHT=20></img></a></l3>

<l4><img STYLE="border:none;" SRC="Flag.jpg" ALT="ILM Airport
1740 Airport Blvd 
Wilmington, NC 28405" WIDTH=24 HEIGHT=20></img></l4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using `=` instead of `:` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

the MOST important thing, you don't have your html tag at the top of the page. You have to have the html tag first, and then on top of that, your title tag MUST be in the head tag.

Comment: It's there in the code. I must have missed it when I was copying the code over. Anyway, I figured it out, thanks t.niese